# Get content after header tag with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am playing with Nokogiri just to learn it and am trying to write a little CL scraper.  Right now I am trying to match up each State on the main page with the cities underneath.  Below is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="colmask">
<div class="box box_1">
<h4>Alabama</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="//auburn.craigslist.org/">auburn</a></li>
<li><a href="//bham.craigslist.org/">birmingham</a></li>
<li><a href="//dothan.craigslist.org/">dothan</a></li>
<li><a href="//shoals.craigslist.org/">florence / muscle shoals</a></li>
<li><a href="//gadsden.craigslist.org/">gadsden-anniston</a></li>
<li><a href="//huntsville.craigslist.org/">huntsville / decatur</a></li>
<li><a href="//mobile.craigslist.org/">mobile</a></li>
<li><a href="//montgomery.craigslist.org/">montgomery</a></li>
<li><a href="//tuscaloosa.craigslist.org/">tuscaloosa</a></li>
</ul>
<h4>Alaska</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="//anchorage.craigslist.org/">anchorage / mat-su</a></li>
<li><a href="//fairbanks.craigslist.org/">fairbanks</a></li>
<li><a href="//kenai.craigslist.org/">kenai peninsula</a></li>
<li><a href="//juneau.craigslist.org/">southeast alaska</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can already pull out just this div class of "colmask" easy enough.  But now I am just trying to get the UL directly after each h4, but can't find a way to do it so far.  Suggestions?

Comment: have a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657468/nokogiri-navigating-the-dom

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". When asking a question, it's really important to show your attempt at solving the problem. That information helps us create a detailed answer, rather than having to start at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get ul elements after h4 using `following-sibling`:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<-EOF
<div class="colmask">
<div class="box box_1">
<h4>Alabama</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="//auburn.craigslist.org/">auburn</a></li>
<li><a href="//bham.craigslist.org/">birmingham</a></li>
<li><a href="//dothan.craigslist.org/">dothan</a></li>
<li><a href="//shoals.craigslist.org/">florence / muscle shoals</a></li>
<li><a href="//gadsden.craigslist.org/">gadsden-anniston</a></li>
<li><a href="//huntsville.craigslist.org/">huntsville / decatur</a></li>
<li><a href="//mobile.craigslist.org/">mobile</a></li>
<li><a href="//montgomery.craigslist.org/">montgomery</a></li>
<li><a href="//tuscaloosa.craigslist.org/">tuscaloosa</a></li>
</ul>
<h4>Alaska</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="//anchorage.craigslist.org/">anchorage / mat-su</a></li>
<li><a href="//fairbanks.craigslist.org/">fairbanks</a></li>
<li><a href="//kenai.craigslist.org/">kenai peninsula</a></li>
<li><a href="//juneau.craigslist.org/">southeast alaska</a></li>
</ul>
EOF

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath('//h4/following-sibling::ul').each do |node|
  puts node.to_html
end
```

To select ul after an h4 with exact text:

```
puts doc.xpath("//h4[text()='Alabama']/following-sibling::ul")[0].to_html
```

Comment: You beat me to it, but to get what the poster is looking for, I think you need to change it to be nested. Change the first selector to `//h4` then iterate on that and get following sibling. Otherwise they will not get the state in the h4 paired without traversal.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!  One question on it though, is it possible to specify which h4 to use?  so h4.Alabama or so on?  I am trying on a different section in the CL site where it is a H1 with a link with the text US.  So I would have thought h1.a.US, but it isn't working.

Comment: You can select on that with `//h4[contains(text(),'Alabama')]`, then process the resulting `NodeSet` with the `following-sibling` axis

Comment: @MichaelPapile strange, but not `contains(text(),'Alabama')` nor `text()='Alabama'` doesn't work for me

Comment: Really?   `doc.xpath("//h4[contains(text(),'Alabama')]")[0]
 => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe15c81bbe0 name="h4" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe15c81b99c "Alabama">]> `  I wrapped my doc with a root node if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MichaelPapile ah really, my bad, I should've selected only first element from array, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<h4>Alabama</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="//auburn.craigslist.org/">auburn</a></li>
<li><a href="//bham.craigslist.org/">birmingham</a></li>
</ul>
<h4>Alaska</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="//anchorage.craigslist.org/">anchorage / mat-su</a></li>
<li><a href="//fairbanks.craigslist.org/">fairbanks</a></li>
</ul>
EOT

states = doc.search('h4')
states_and_cities = states.map{ |state|
  cities = state.next_element.search('li a')
  [state.text, cities.map(&:text)]
}.to_h
```

At this point `states_and_cities` is a hash of arrays:

```
states_and_cities
# => {"Alabama"=>["auburn", "birmingham"],
#     "Alaska"=>["anchorage / mat-su", "fairbanks"]}
```

If you're concerned about having a big structure, it'd be very easy to convert `states` to a hash where each state's name is a key, and the associated value is the state's node. Then, that node could be grabbed to find only the cities for the particular state.

However, if you're running this code to generate content for a web-page on the fly, then you're going about it wrong. The information for states and cities should be dumped into a database where it can be accessed much more quickly. Then you won't have to do it every time the page is generated.

Being kind and gentle to other sites is important; Research the `HEAD` HTTP request. It's your key to determining whether you should retrieve a page in full. Also, learn how to sniff the cache information from the HTTP header returned from a server. That tells you what your minimum refresh rate should be. Also, pay attention to the robots.txt file, which tells you what they consider safe for you to scrape; ignoring that can lead to being banned.

Comment: That is what I was just thinking about.  It will be for a webpage.  Right now I was just trying to find how to pull the info I wanted, now I'm deciding what I want to do with it.  I think the easiest would be to just dump it to a db on a scheduled task.

Comment: Good. I added additional information for courteous scraping.